# Dynamic text on My Account link to include user's name

Tags: 7, routes, users

I'm using a Commerce Kickstart 2 profile and I'd like the "My Account" link at the top to include the name or email of the user who is currently logged in. Right now it says `My account` but I'd like it to be something like `My Account (bob@gmail.com)`.

Similar to the way the admin menu shows my name in the top right "Hello Kenny Wyland", is there a way to do that with the `My account` link?

I know that menus are static and cached, so I can't use them directly, but what is a standard way of providing that kind of personalized account menu link?

[image]

Comment: This answer should help: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/53345/633

Comment: Thank you, Andy. The `menu_tokens` module was exactly what I was looking for.