# Modifying a single menu link title

Tags: routes, navigation

I'd like to replace the link title on the top link of my secondary navbar (called "explorer", links to "mysite.net/explorer", but actually just triggers a dropdown-menu) with a glyphicon and the current user's name.

[According to this thread](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28642/change-menu-link-title-dynamically), a title callback is the way to do this. However, adding this code in my template.php has no effect at all.

```
function mythemename_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['explorer']['title callback'] = 'mythemename_title_callback';
}

function mythemename_title_callback($arg1, $arg2) {
  global $user;
  $title = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>'. $user->name;

  return $title;
}
```

What am i doing wrong? And why does the callback function take 2 parameters? (It doesn't work with 1 or 0 params.)

The "menu token" module almost crashed my site after installation, so I don't want to use that.

Comment: Is mysite.net/explorer added by a module, or does it point to a page you created, including a view?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change the title of an menu item, you should be able to do this through the administration. Go to `admin/structure/menu` and edit the correct item in your secondary menu.

To use `hook_menu_alter()` you must add it in a custom module not inside your template file. Remember to clear you cache in order for the changes to take effect. To clear the cache you can goto `admin/config/development/performance`.

Comment: Themes can implement alter hooks. The problem is that `hook_menu_alter()` is used to alter what `hook_menu()` returns, not to alter links added within the user interface.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - I tried adding it to my own template file and cleared my cache, but the hook never seemed to be called, so I assumed that one was forced to use a custom module for this.

Comment: See [drupal_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21module.inc/function/drupal_alter/7), the code after the "Allow the theme to alter variables after the theme system has been initialized" comment. It is adding `$theme_key . '_' . $hook` to the `$functions[$cid]` array of the called functions.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - Strange I cant get it to work? Hm I must have made some kind of error.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `theme_menu_link()`. Use [`debug()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/debug/7) or [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel)'s [`dpm()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/7) to browse through `$variables` in order to get a grip on how the array is structured. Then locate the particular menu link in your code and theme it to your requirements. In the [API documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/theme_menu_link/7) there are plenty of examples in the comment area that may suit your needs.

Comment: Theme functions should be used to alter the way an element is rendered, not to alter a link title. Eventually, the OP should use a preprocess function, but I think an alter hook should be used.

Comment: Sure. I should have said 'One quick but dirty way'.