# How do I dynamically change the title of a menu link?

Tags: routes

I made a menu in administration, structures, menu. I want to change the title, as it appears on the menu, of one of the links based on the gender of the currently logged in user.

I have found several answers to similar questions but I can't figure out how to implement the solutions. Some of them suggest using hook_menu_alter(&$items) and a separate callback function, but I don't understand the structure of $items. I was hoping to just print out the value of $items, find the string I wanted to change, and change that value in $items in the hook. Apparently, though, you can't debug the $items variable because hook_menu_alter is rarely called. I tried to figure out the structure of $items from a bunch of other questions and answers and I found stuff like this:

```
$items['user/%user_category/edit']['title']
```

Why is 'title' a property of a path? Does this mean that every menu on your site that has a link to that path will display the title that you set the above variable to? What if you wanted a link to a specific path on one menu to have a different label than a link to that path on another menu? Isn't there somewhere I can access and change the title of a menu link like this

```
$allMenuData['My Custom Menu']['an item on my menu']['title']
```

Comment: This has already been asked/solved in the past: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28642/change-menu-link-title-dynamically

Comment: I just tried that solution again, for good measure. I have a menu link title of "Site Users" and it links to a page called "main-profiles". I made a function called alter_callback() that returns a string. In the hook_menu_alter, I tried $items['Site Users']['title callback'] = "alter_callback" and I tried $items['main-profiles']['title callback'] = "alter_callback" and neither of them have any effect on the menu link title. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you cleared your cache?

Comment: Yes. For both tests, I cleared the cache, disabled the module, re-enabled the module and cleared the cache again.

Comment: Oké I suggest debugging the code with Xdebug to see what is/isn't running. You could also do this with dsm's of course.

Comment: Could you post your full code?

Comment: The hook_menu_alter gets called but the callback doesn't. I suspect I'm using $items wrong. I put a dsm() in the hook to show me all of the keys from the $items array on the admin page when I reset the cache and it showed me hundreds of keys. They are all paths like "admin/structure/block", etc. Out of curiosity, I added a new shortcut to the admin shortcuts bar to see if it's title or path would show up in the dsm'd list of $item's keys and neither showed up. I just can't figure out $items. I'm going to work on getting xdebug to install. It's linux instructions aren't working for me yet.

Comment: I've never posted code in a comment before... bear with me. *edit: I can't figure out how to post it in a comment.
'
function assorted_menu_alter(&$items) {
// $items['Site Users']['title callback'] = "assorted_alter_callback";
 $items['main-profiles']['title callback'] = "assorted_alter_callback";
}

function assorted_alter_callback() {
 return "something";
}
'

Comment: I finally got hook_menu_alter to work, but on a different menu (the user-menu). The menu I want to modify is a superfish menu. I found this post: http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=fr&u=http://drupalfr.org/forum/support/developpement/32014-hookmenualter&prev=search

Comment: @Jason it's my understanding that hook_menu_alter() is meant to alter menu items defined in hook_menu() before they are saved to the {menu_router} table in the database. If I'm not mistaken you're creating link items through the UI and not through hook_menu(), these are not saved to {menu_router}, just {menu_links} and I don't believe you're going to be able modify them that way. The menu links where you had success, I believe, all have their paths defined in a module's hook_menu().

Comment: I was trying to make sense of how the menu data is stored in the database, but I had trouble with that. My menu_router table only has "admin/..." paths. My menu_links table doesn't have any of my custom menu links that I created in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You might try hook_preprocess_menu_link()

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_menu_link(&$variables) {
    global $user;

    if (isset($variables['element']['#original_link']['menu_name'])
        && $variables['element']['#original_link']['menu_name'] == 'my-menu-machine-name'
        && $variables['element']['#title'] == 'ORIGINAL LINK TITLE') {

        $new_title = (check for gender) ? 'New title 1' : 'New title 2';
        $variables['element']['#title'] = $new_title;
    }
}
```

Fill in your menu machine name, the title you want to change, the conditional for the gender and the new titles depending on the gender value.

Comment: That didn't work, so I tried to var_dump($variables['element]['#main-profiles']) from that hook and it says #main-profiles is an undefined index. main-profiles is definitely the link in my menu.

Comment: the only spots you should need to change are 'my-menu-machine-name', 'ORIGINAL LINK TITLE', the conditional, and 'New Title 1', 'New Title 2'. the #original_link key should not be changed.

Comment: It worked! Thank you. Also, I had some luck with hook_menu_alter hook. I'll post details in a comment above.